# Common properties between revit and naviswork to map objects

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-navisworks

We are facing the issue for finding some **common properties/ids** so that we can map **revit model object id** with **naviswork model objects**. Can you please let us to find any common properties/id?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Building Coder has already done so:

- [Element Id – Export, Unique, Navisworks and Other Ids](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/element-id-export-unique-navisworks-and-other-ids.html)
- [Element Identifiers in RVT, IFC, NW and Forge](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/07/element-identifiers-in-rvt-ifc-nw-and-forge.html)